# Checking for "undefined" and then sorting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data that is an array of objects loaded from csv. I would like to filter out the undesirable values and sort the remaining values and put them in another array for me to load a "select" element in javascript.

```
0: Object { type: "Feature", id: "AFG", female_lfpr: "48.65999985", … }
​​
1: Object { type: "Feature", id: "AGO", female_lfpr: "75.41200256", … }
​​
2: Object { type: "Feature", id: "ALB", female_lfpr: "47.19100189", … }
```

The "data.features" looks like above. I would like to remove countries where id is -99 or where country_name is "" or "undefined" and collect the valid country id and names in another array.

```
const valid_countries = {};
valid_countries = data.features.sort(function(a, b)
{
  if ( (typeof a.country_name !== 'undefined') && (a.id !== '-99') &&(a.country_name !== ""))
  {
        valid_countries.id = a.id
        valid_countries.country_name = a.country_name
        // return a.country_name.localeCompare(b.country_name); 
  }
});
```

I need an array valid_countries that has an id as well as corresponding country name.

```
{id: AUS, name:Australia}
{id: USA, name:United States of America}
```

which can be used to populate a "select" options and values such that the country names are listed in alphabetical order.

```
d3.select('#country_dropdown') 
        .selectAll("option")
        .data(valid_countries)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", function(c){ return c.id; })
        .text(function(c) { return c.country_name; });
```

Comment: "*where id is -99 **or***" shouldn't you be using a  logical OR then `||` instead of AND `&&`?

Comment: So why don't you *array.filter()* first and then *array.sort()*, just like you described in your question?

Comment: @Robert I completely missed this was done in a `.sort`, not a `.filter`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your original array looks something like:

```
const data = [{ type: "Feature", id: "AFG", female_lfpr: "48.65999985", country_name: "Afghanistan" }, { type: "Feature", id: "AGO", female_lfpr: "75.41200256" }, { type: "Feature", id: "ALB", female_lfpr: "47.19100189", country_name: "Albania" }];
```

You can filter out the invalids with something like

```
const filtered = data.filter(element => { return (element.country_name != null && element.country_name !== '-99')})
```

Above the `!= null` checks for 0-length string and `undefined`.

And then sort with

```
const sorted = filtered.sort((a, b) => { return /* your comparison here*/ });
```

If you need to transform the result to format of `{ id: 'id', name: 'name'}`, this can be achieved by calling

```
const result = sorted.map(item => { id: item.id, name: item.country_name });
```

Comment: Thank You Niko. I don't understand the last line that involves "map". Once I sort, I get back sorted country names only, right ?  Won't I loose the id ?

Comment: Ah ! I got it ! Thank You very much !!!! Have been sitting on it trying to filtering with IF condition and sorting inside the same function.